# Get directions from an Android device to another

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using [Google Maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Maps) and getting latitude/longitude. I have a conundrum:

Let's say I have an Android device in one room (at home) facing upright (device A) and another Android device in a flat position (device B). I would like to find out which direction device 'A' is facing and directions to that device from device 'B'. Also, if it is possible, how do I find the path to that device?

Is there a solution I can apply for the above requirement? Even via Bluetooth, if possible.
In short, how can device 'A' get to device 'B' in a room?

Comment: You are asking us to make 'almost' an app-module! Try playing with sensors and their combinations. Write some code.
See this link and download the app-- it has a similar implementation.
http://www.navigale.com

Comment: Thank You Kunal.Please could you suggest few more example or break it down to few units and maybe push me in the direction of implementation of similar feature.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just start with simple algorithm for drawing a line between coordinates of A and B. Once that's done, you can consider orientation and see what difference it make, perhaps you don't even need to care about orientation at all, as usually a device is of a relatively small size. Drawing a line between two coordinates on the same plane is really quite simple. If you need to take care what roads you take, then you can just start by playing with URL parameters of Google Maps in the browser.

Comment: Thank you Sir but How do I get the path at home .From one room to another (Using google maps? or is there any other way to get distance in a smaller space?)Thanks for your time.